# PHP/SQL/XML with with googlemaps V3 api not working

Tags: php, javascript, sql, xml, google-maps

I'm trying to add a map to my webpage, which shows markers loaded from an SQL database. I'm following the googlemaps api V3 tutorial here (https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#createmap) to get an idea how to do this. However, as simple as it should be, I can't get it to work and it's very frustrating!

Here is my PHP file, called "phpsqlajax_genxml.php"

```
<?php
require("phpsqlinfo_dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
echo '<marker ';
echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

When I access this page in the browser, the XML output works in Chrome, but not in Safari.

Then I'm using javascript to try and load the map and markers, however all I ever get is a blank page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_api_key&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[[]i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[[]i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[[]i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[[]i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[[]i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[[]type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>

</script>

</head>

<body onload="load()">
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: First thing's first, is your XML valid?

Comment: Yes. At least I think so. When I run the php script in Chrome, the XML output is valid (and the same as in the tutorial). But with Safari, it just gives a blank page.

Comment: (i) try running it through an online XML validation service (ii) look at the browser's JavaScript console (try pressing F12) and post any JavaScript errors you see there

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to get it working in the end.